# How to improve modale popup

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I will wish to appear this type of window after an error message.

[image]

Here is my result

[image]

How to I could get the same result please?

```
<!-- Modal -->
<ng-template #mymodal let-modal>
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Error message</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close button" aria-describedby="modal-title" (click)="modal.dismiss('Cross click')">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>
  </div>

  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>This is a text</td>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Ok</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kr7cyd?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? You have all the elements that the example shows (plus an "Ok" button). What remains is styling, and your pasted code and stackblitz don't have any css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `.modal-footer` would achieve that..

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="modal.close('Save click')">Ok</button>
</div>
```